# param is missing or the value is empty: ad

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table of "ads" with attributes that include title

ads_controller.rb

```
def index
    if params[:title]
   @ad = Ad.where('title LIKE ?', "%#{params[:title]}%")
 else
   @ads = Ad.published.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
 end
    @categories = Category.all
    @categorytypes = Categorytype.all
  end
```

Application.html.erb

```
  <%= form_tag(ads_path method: :get) do %>
             <%= text_field_tag :title, params[:title], class: 'form-control' %>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            <% end %>
```

When I submit, I get an error message:

param is missing or the value is empty: ad

 `def ad_params
    params.require(:ad).permit(:title, :description, :price, :location, :category_id, images: [])
   end`

any solutions ?

Comment: I am not certain how this `<%= form_tag(ads_path method: :get) do %>` does not raise a syntax error of some kind but please post the form that is actually generated by this method.

Answer (score 0):

When you are submitting the form you are not submitting it with the proper params type. In your controller, you are expecting it in the format of `params[:ad][:title]` because of `ad_params` method . But you are currently getting the parameters as `params[:title]` . So that's the reason you are facing this issue.

Now coming to the solution, you can change you form's text field tag as this :

```
<%= text_field_tag "ad[title]", nil, class: "form-control" %>
```

Comment: i don't know why but when i click on submit it redirect me to create method